# How to keep SEO URLs after migrating my website to WordPress?

Tags: seo, url, wordpress, transfer, clean-urls

Because each platform has a unique structure and different rules for URLs, SEO URLs may be changed when migrating data from one content management platform to another.

Do I have have to use an extension from a third party or fix the URL structure manually?

Comment: I dont think that it is possible to migrate product cart to cart. After completing data transfer, all addresses change. It is difficult.

Comment: Have got any examples of the urls?

Answer (score 2):

On WordPress install a plugin to do 301 redirects... Yoast SEO and Redirection plugin both do this.

They allow you to input the old URLs, and map them individually to the new URL's.

I would advised first making a spreadsheet with all your old urls indexed by google, and submitted by your old xml sitemaps.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not sure about your technical knowledge, I think the good choice is hiring a freelancer to check your problem. In my opinion, I do not think google ranking can migrate after changing website. Maybe this guideline can help you https://shoppingcartmigration.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/seo-urls-migration-plugin-solution-to-keep-search-ranking/

Comment: This answer is not particularly helpful.  It is little more than an external link and a suggestion to hire somebody.   On this site we strive to put enough information into answers to be helpful without requiring either hiring somebody, or clicking to another page.